# Create 2D array with large number in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, 2d, unhandled-exception

Hello Guys i am doing my assignemt creating cleaning agent, which will clean givin area in 2D space and space is 200,000 X 200,000.

I have done 99% of my assignemtn but only one thing is left, This 2D boolean array with large number. Once i tried to create this array with following tradational way,

```
private bool[,] map= new bool[200000, 200000];
```

no success, then i tried this:

```
int length= 100000;
bool[][] map= new bool[length][];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   map[i] = new bool[length];
```

I received the same

```
Unhandled Exception : OutOfMemoryException
```

Please help me, My assignemtn works flawless with small number, I have done all my coding and logic but this one problem appears at the end :(

Comment: Unless you have ~40 GB of RAM, there is nothing you can do. You could use a bit array to get down to ~5 GB but that's all. The only chance you have is to use disk memory in a file. The more reasonable way, however, would be to alter your algorithm to work with a reasonable amount of memory.

Comment: this is my question: if you can give me some idea, how can i map this array into some text file or some bit manuplation...

Comment: That depends on what you need to do with the data.

Comment: consider this 2D array as a room space. and vaccume will move around and clean and set the array values true....

Comment: Maybe, [Memory Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) are worth considering.